# PHP/MySQL - Ranking based on last db column

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

I’ve two tables (MySQL): player and scores. In scores table are stored annual scores in this way:

```
player_id | 2002 | 2003 | 2004
        1 |  5   |  6   |  4
        2 |  3   |  2   |  5
               Etc.
```

I write the follow code to make a ranking based on last year scores.

```
$extract = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players AS p, scores AS s WHERE p.player_id =s.player_id ORDER BY s.2004 desc"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($extract)) { 
    $name = $row['name'];      
    $score = $row['2004']; 

    if ($row['2004'] < $row['2003']) { 
     $value = "-"; 
    } 
    else if ($row['2004'] > $row['2003']) { 
     $value = "+"; 
    }     
    else if ($row['2004'] == $row['2003']) { 
     $value = "="; 
    }     

echo "<b>".$name."</b> | ".$score." ".$value."<br>\n"; 
}
```

But this code has two big problems:

1) In the query  I have to specify the last year (ORDER BY s.2004), so if I add another column (eg. 2005) into scores table, I have to manually change the code.

2) Same thing for the “$value” var. If I add 2005, the comparison between 2004 and 2003 becomes wrong (it should be between 2005 and 2004).

I know I have to use loops and array but... how?

Answer (score 0):

You should redesign your `scores` table to store player_id, score and year in one row. So, each score gets its own row. When you find yourself duplicating columns, you are usually heading in the wrong direction.

Then, your query would look like:

Select Year(CURDATE());

```
select * 
from players p
inner join scores s on p.player_id = s.player_id 
where s.`Year` = Year(CURDATE()) --or (select max(Year) from Score)
```